# c:import is always pointing to jsp itself

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
hello
<c:import url="/scripts/script.js"  var="under" context="/"/>
<c:out value="${under}"/>
bye
```

"script.js" refers to an external file.  However, when I add that statement, the import always grabs the file that I am working on instead.  I get the following output:

> "hello <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> hello   bye bye"

Why is this?  What can I do to point to the correct jsp?

Comment: Do you have the JSTL libraries in the classpath?

Comment: You're saying that without the import the page works correctly including properly dealing with the directive?

Comment: why don't you use directly use the `<script>`?

Comment: Go to `http://localhost:8080/scripts/script.js`. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Is your script (/scripts/script.js) contains "bye"?

- I can c:out is working fine so JSTL library is in classpath ( ruled out)
- We can see out for under var (bye in this case)

That clearly says your javascript file should contain "bye".